# How to wrap an array response to object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have a model called `history` and then i want to render it.

my current code is like :

```
class Address < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :guid, :name, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :place_id, :notes, :last_used_on

  def latitude
    object.latitude.to_s
  end

  def longitude
    object.longitude.to_s
  end
end
```

and the response is

```
[
  {
    "guid"=>"Address-35-91526dee",
    "name"=>"Lake Johana",
    "address"=>"Apt. 951 774 Bruen Mountains, Schneiderchester, OK 90705-0506",
    "latitude"=>"67.24423261517666",
    "longitude"=>"96.37355099166064",
    "place_id"=>"ltpzw5n87w",
    "notes"=>"c2rxzesry7",
    "last_used_on"=>"2018-11-05 09:56:23 +0700"
  },
  {
    "guid"=>"Address-34-23f95e54",
    "name"=>"North Gregoryshire",
    "address"=>"64213 Vandervort Trail, North Marinville, CA 70667",
    "latitude"=>"-45.928682957769965",
    "longitude"=>"124.27899877429144",
    "place_id"=>"hwki1m0xwg",
    "notes"=>"k34un21zjh",
    "last_used_on"=>"2018-11-05 09:56:23 +0700"
  }
]
```

what i want is to wrap the response inside `addresses`, so it will looks like

```
{
  "addresses": [
    {
      "guid": "AddressHistory-16-58abd401",
      "name": "Port Charla",
      "address": "5016 Kerstin Brook, West Tanja, MO 02060",
      "latitude": "-68.07486131158515",
      "longitude": "-8.531218394535387",
      "place_id": "9guhaf7o1e",
      "notes": "rl5qq7r7cv",
      "last_used_on": "2018-11-05 09:42:51 +0700",
    },
    {
      "guid": "AddressHistory-15-86bea685",
      "name": "South Vernon",
      "address": "1185 Tania Road, South Joeyborough, OK 97125",
      "latitude": "84.52009358082654",
      "longitude": "87.74343692672034",
      "place_id": "hiw08eeh0l",
      "notes": "8nn5aiwe9m",
      "last_used_on": "2018-11-05 09:42:51 +0700",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Official guides [link](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/howto/add_root_key.md)

Answer (score 0):

```
a=Hash.new
a['addresses']=response
```

Comment: As you can see, the class mentioned in the comment inherits from `ActiveModel::Serializer` and adding roots to AMS responses has to be done automatically (to generate root key correctly).

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.